# Create a floating box over an image, with another floating box inside of another color HTML

Tags: html, css

Im attempting to overlay a semi-transparent box over an image. Inside that box i would like the bottom 1/4 to be red (indicating an item purchased on sale). So far i have the image, and a semi-transparent white box over the image.

2 things currently: 1. How can i make the bottom ~1/4 of the box red 2. How can i separate/style the text i have so the Price appears at the bottom of the box in the red area (if sale), and the description appears above like in the reference image below.

Do I need to create a frame or padding around the image to ensure the boxes float in the same place?

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3S9Dg/

What i designed that i'm trying to work towards trying to emulate for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8198n.jpg

The red box inside the box is on the first item on the left, the girl in the vest.

```
<DIV style="position: absolute; top:265px; left:125px; width:200px; height:25px"><p>Sex    Dress <span id="u186-2">IN </span></p>
<p><span id="u186-4">Purple rain</span> <div class="Cash-Money" id="u187-4">
<p>Price : $455</p></DIV></p>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; top:165px; left:40px">    
<style>
div.transbox
{
width:150px;
height:65px;
margin:30px 50px;
background-color:#ffffff;
border:0px solid black;
opacity:0.81;
filter:alpha(opacity=81);
}
div.transbox p
{
margin:30px 40px;
font-weight:italics;
color:#000000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="background">
<div class="transbox">
<p><font size="1">Magic Sex Shirt In Shizam
 Price: $265</font>
</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You have serious problems with your HTML syntax: why is the `<head>` element in the middle of the page content? p/s: Inline CSS has got to go.

Comment: Sorry first time writing any code. Im sure its a mess.

Comment: Fix it, so that we can help you. Strip out all inline CSS from your Fiddle, leaving only the content in the HTML tab. Move the inline CSS over to the CSS tab instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, you'll have to start over from the beginning before anyone can help you and keep their sanity! This is not how HTML code is supposed to look.

Here is a basic structure:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page title</title>
    </head>

    <style>
        #example {
            color:red;
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div id="example"><p>Example Div Content</p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggested structure

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/HG7Wk/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="product">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-h-c-250-480-10.jpg" alt=""/>
    <div class="description">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        <span class="price sale">Sale Price $500</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.product {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.product img {
    display:block;
}

.description {
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    top:60%;;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}

.description span {
    display:block;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:5px;
}
.sale {
    background:red;

}
```

Feel free to adjust as required.

Comment: The only issue i have now is i increased the size of the image. How do i ensure the floating box stays centered and "fits" as the image gets bigger?

http://jsfiddle.net/dUWEE/

http://imgur.com/yc4nNLa

Comment: Thanks Paulie

That centers the picture and text. But i want the text and transparent box to "fit" inside the div/image. Also how do i make the box smaller?

Comment: Which box is to be smaller...and what does 'fit' mean exactly. Feel free to change some widths or remove padding etc to see what happens.

Comment: Basically it looks like this currently http://imgur.com/rl5YYET
I'd like for the text box (white transparent and red) to fit to the image width.

Comment: As I said, feel free to play with the widths / margins / padding etc. It's all adaptable. http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/HG7Wk/7/